# Are all variants of English spelling basically British or American?

Tags: american-english, british-english, orthography, canadian-english, south-african-english

I am working on an English-language online resource. It seems an obvious good idea to allow users to choose a version in British English or American English spelling. However, I've noticed that spell-checkers also provide options such as Canadian English, Australian English, South-African English, Jamaican English, Hong Kong English, and so on. I have always assumed that these variants are all basically British or American, with maybe a few minor details that are different. So my question is:

**Are any of the other variants of English spelling significantly different from British or American spelling?**

With significantly different, I mean that they don't just add a number of new words, like "wee" or "bairn" in Scotland, or French loan-words in Canada, but that basic English words are spelled differently, in the way that e.g. "colour/color", "analyse/analyze" and "theatre/theater" are spelled differently in the UK/USA.

*(To be clear: I'm only interested in how great the difference is to an outside observer, not how important it is to e.g. a Canadian person to be able to select "Canadian English" instead of having to select "British English". I'm also not interested in differences in grammar.)*

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145835/discussion-on-question-by-english-mcenglishface-are-all-variants-of-english-spel); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 3):

Whether differences are "significant" is a matter of opinion. The dichotomy of US-UK is a simplification (for example, the spelling *—ize* is not exclusively American, but can also be found in some British writers). You could group [Canadian English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canadian_English#Spelling) and [Australian English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australian_English#Spelling_and_style) spelling with British English, but Canadian writers tend to use *-ize* spellings, like American writers.